# Securing communications between PoS terminals and sTunnel server

Tags: windows, public-key-infrastructure, pci-dss

Am I correct in thinking that a PoS Terminal only needs my public key installed on the device to connect to my sTunnel server (with Private key) and that communications between client and server will be secure?